# Thin over SSL through Apache doesn't perform handshake

Tags: apache, ssl, thin

I'm running PrivatePub on a Thin server using SSL / Apache.

I have a Thin config file like so:

```
ssl: true
cert_chain_file: "{cert directory}/fullchain.pem"
ssl_key_file: "{cert directory}/privkey.pem"
environment: "production"
rackup: "private_pub.ru"
```

And I run thin using:

```
$ bundle exec thin -p 9292 -C config/private_pub_thin.yml start
```

Where `private_pub_thin.yml` is the above config file.

The server starts up with no problems and does find the certificate files - which are the same I'm using for my Rails server and have checked using Qualys.

However my Rails server is having trouble connecting to Thin. I used `openssl` to try and figure out what the problem was:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect 0.0.0.0:9292
```

Returns:

```
140388916979344:error:140790E5:SSL routines:ssl23_write:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
CONNECTED(00000003)
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 315 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
---
```

With no errors on the Thin side.

I'm not sure how to proceed in figuring out why Thin isn't doing a proper handshake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. The problem appears to have been that thin wasn't using the config file properly. It was definitely parsing it and checking for the existence of the SSL cert chain and key files, as I confirmed by dropping debug lines *in the actual gem source*, but somehow not using them properly to do the SSL handshake.

Passing the SSL cert chain and key file as command line options rather than in a separate config file worked fine.